# Sorting in Google apps scripts by a named column

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am interested in writing a function that would sort some rows with respect to values in a named column. For example, suppose I have named the range A3:C8 as Data, and column A (i.e. A:A) as Surname, and I want to order it with respect to surname. Something like the following code does this

```
function sortBySurname() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
    var range = ss.getRangeByName("Data");

    range.sort(1); 
}
```

However, I would like to achieve the same without explicitly using the fact that column Surname is the first one, i.e. what's the right way to write 
`range.sort("Surname")` instead of `range.sort(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function that takes in the header name as an argument and sorts the range under that header. Hope that helps.

**Update**

I updated the answer to account for your comment below

```
function sortByRangeName(rangeName){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var namedRange = ss.getRangeByName(rangeName);
  var startCol = namedRange.getColumn();
  var lastCol = namedRange.getLastColumn();

  var dataRange = ss.getRangeByName("Data");
  var columnForSorting = (startCol <= dataRange.getLastColumn()) ? startCol : null;


  if (namedRange && (startCol == lastCol) && columnForSorting) {

    dataRange.sort({column: columnForSorting, ascending: false});

  } else {

    throw new Error(Utilities.formatString("Range name: %s, startCol: %s, lastCol: %s, columnForSorting: %s", header, startCol, lastCol, columnForSorting));

  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, this doesn't completely answer my question as my table doesn't have a header which would indicate which column is Surname. Instead, the column in question is a named range, as in Data -> Named ranges...

Comment: Your named range is two-dimensional (contains multiple rows and columns).  You should either assign a named range for each column or create a configuration object linking column number to it string value

Comment: Updated my original answer